# NodeJS module with equivalente google isLocationOnEdge

Tags: node.js, geolocation, geometry, polyline

Is there a NodeJS Module with a method that can replace google maps geometry and especially google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge method ?

Many Thanks !